# $query->result_array() wipes away list_fields() data

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm having an issue where I call the `result_array()` function on n query object from in codeigniter:

```
   $this->db->select(array('a','b','c'));

   $query = $this->db->get('basic');
   print_r($query->list_fields());
   $test = $query->result_array();
   print_r($query->list_fields());
```

When I run this code, or:

```
   $query = $this->db->get('basic');
   print_r($query->list_fields());
   print_r($query->list_fields());
```

or:

```
   $query = $this->db->get('basic');
   $test = $query->result_array();
   print_r($query->list_fields());
```

The second `list_fields()` function always returns an array size 0, the first returns the correct list of field names.

In the last example where there is only one list_fields() function, the array is again size zero.

Any guidance in this matter will be greatly appreciated. I need the `list_fields()` function to be accessible after I read the `result_array()`.

Here is the result of the first block of code:

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => site_id
        [1] => institution
        [2] => caller
        [3] => call_complete
        [4] => call_details
        [5] => id
        [6] => timestamp
    )
    Array
    (
    )
```

Thank you, for your help

Comment: `$fields = $query->list_fields(); ...; var_dump($fields);` @gSaenz your comment "`var_dump` clears the contents of a variable" makes no sense.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I apologize for my confusion with var_dump, I was using it here in place of print_r. In response cbuckley, I need $query gets passed into another function later down the line which reads the field data of the query.

Comment: What happens if you do as cbuckley says and define `$query->list_fields()` as a variable?

Comment: The variable is stored properly, with the full list of fields. However, if I then run $query->list_fields() again, an empty array is returned. This method will be a last resort for me just because I would have to rewrite some other functions down the line since the later functions use $query->list_fields() instead of a separate variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks to be a bug in the database driver. For example, in [`CI_DB_mysqli_result`](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_result.php#L74):

```
public function list_fields()
{
    $field_names = array();
    while ($field = $this->result_id->fetch_field())
    {
        $field_names[] = $field->name;
    }

    return $field_names;
}
```

A subsequent call will return `array()` because the while loop seeks over all the fields and leaves the pointer at the end of the list.

However, in the result class, `result_id` is public, so you can use [mysqli_result::field_seek](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.field-seek.php):

```
$query = $this->db->get('basic');
var_dump($query->list_fields());

// this should be called before any call to list_fields()
$query->result_id->field_seek(0);
var_dump($query->list_fields());
```

However, this is bad practise, as this only works for mysqli; for mysql, you'll need this:

```
mysql_field_seek($query->result_id, 0);
```

and for mssql:

```
mssql_field_seek($query->result_id, 0);
```

The correct way to do this is really to fix it in the database drivers. See [this pull request](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/pull/2204) :-)

Comment: Thank you for the answer cbuckley, however, this still occurs if I just pull the result_array and not just the list_fields call. Would your answer still apply in that case?

Comment: Yes, but since other methods may cause the seek offset to change, you should call `field_seek(0)` *before* you make any call to `list_fields()`, just to be sure.

Comment: Thank you again, this make sense to me. However, whenever I attempt this I get a fatal error: Fatal error:  Call to a member function field_seek() on a non-object. I checked it out, and $query->result_id is definitely an array. Is there another way to reset the field_seek?

Comment: What database driver are you using? An array is not an object, BTW. Try using `var_dump` instead of `print_r`; the former is more useful for debugging. As long as nothing has called `$query->free_result()`, this should be fine.

Comment: it is mysqli. Thank you again, and thank you for the var_dump tip.

Comment: Another way this could be done is to edit the actual code in codeigniter, would there be a way to reset the field_seek in the list_fields() function? I cannot seem to find a way...

Comment: here is the result of a var_dump($query->result_id)
resource(37) of type (mysql result)
Array
(
)

Comment: Hmm, that's **mysql**, not **mysqli**. In that case, you'll need to do something slightly different: `mysql_field_seek($query->result_id, 0);`. Have a look at [this PR](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/pull/2204), and my edit above.